# Adding conditions to php upload file script

Tags: php

here I tried to customize this common php script responsible of multiple file upload

In the second line `$extensions = array('mp4', 'mp3', 'aac');` is used to allow only some extensions.

How can I do to allow upload only when the user select many files with specific names?

Es:

The user must upload only four files with the following names: file1.mp3 file2.mp4 file3.mp4 file4.mp4
Or the upload is deny.

```
<?php 

$max_size = 9000000000000;
$extensions = array('mp4', 'mp3', 'aac');
$dir = 'incoming/';
$count = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{
  // loop all files
  foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
  {
    // if file not uploaded then skip it
    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
      continue;

      // skip large files
    if ( $_FILES['files']['size'][$i] >= $max_size )
      continue;

    // skip unprotected files
    if( !in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions) )
      continue;

    // now we can move uploaded files
      if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
        $count++;
  }

  echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

}

?>
```

Thanks a lot
Gian

Comment: You could do `if (!in_array($name,['file1.mp3','file2.mp4','file3.mp4','file4.mp4'])) continue;` ... but, thats kind of a weird stipulation.

Comment: If its instead to only allow 1 mp3, and 3 mp4s ... then you could pre-loop and count by PATHINFO results and if the conditions are not met, dont even bother with the second loop.

Comment: do you know `9000000000000` is 9TB? and `$_FILES['files']['error']`'s happen?

Comment: Hi, ya, the 9 tb were to avoid issues about file weight, if (!in_array($name,['output_audio.mp4','output_1080.mp4','output_720.mp4','output_360.mp4 , 'output_180.mp4']))
continue; replace the extension check don't work, is a good solution for me, but I don't know why it don't work

Comment: I think that this inside the for each can't work

Comment: I need to check if they are 5 elements and if they have that name